# Rails migration error: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

I just cloned a repository, so I am trying to setup locally, I get this strange error whenever I run `rails db:migrate`, I have searched for a solution but none on here meets my need.

I have been particularly confused at this because it is my first time using rails 6.0 and I cannot tell if it is an issue with rails or something is wrong in the code, although following the trace the issue seems to be with the `timestamps` type but I do not know what to do

Error

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Single arity template handlers are deprecated. Template handlers must
now accept two parameters, the view object and the source for the view object.
Change:
  >> Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template)
To:
  >> Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler.call(template, source)
 (called from <main> at /home/noriodebrume/crowdfrica/config/application.rb:7)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20160807112612 CreateProjects: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:projects, {:id=>:integer})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:20:in `timestamps'
/home/noriodebrume/crowdfrica/db/migrate/20160807112612_create_projects.rb:8:in `block in change'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:44:in `block in create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:309:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:882:in `block in method_missing'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `say_with_time'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:871:in `method_missing'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:44:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:104:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:142:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/crowdfrica/db/migrate/20160807112612_create_projects.rb:3:in `change'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `exec_migration'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:804:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:803:in `block in migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `with_connection'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:802:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1300:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1351:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:277:in `block in transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:272:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:270:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:277:in `transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1351:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1299:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1271:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1270:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1270:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1218:in `block in migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1371:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1218:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1051:in `up'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1026:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:226:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:83:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:81:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:81:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `block in require'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load_dependency'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:20:in `timestamps'
/home/noriodebrume/crowdfrica/db/migrate/20160807112612_create_projects.rb:8:in `block in change'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:44:in `block in create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:309:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:882:in `block in method_missing'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:850:in `say_with_time'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:871:in `method_missing'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:44:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:104:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:142:in `create_table'
/home/noriodebrume/crowdfrica/db/migrate/20160807112612_create_projects.rb:3:in `change'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `exec_migration'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:804:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:803:in `block in migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `with_connection'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:802:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1300:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1351:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:277:in `block in transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:272:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:270:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:277:in `transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1351:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1299:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1271:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1270:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1270:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1218:in `block in migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1371:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1218:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1051:in `up'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1026:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:226:in `migrate'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:83:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:81:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:81:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `block in require'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load_dependency'
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Here is the exact migration it points to:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string     :procect_name,   null: false
      t.numeric    :project_goal
      t.text       :prgoject_headline
      t.text       :prgoject_description 
      t.timestamps :expires_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add that ruby 2.6.3 is used for this project and this warning shows up whenever I run a migration:

```
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.6.3/lib/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:47: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.6.3/lib/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:51: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.6.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/noriodebrume/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-3.6.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
```

Comment: Is `t.timestamps :expires_at` line 8? (It looks like it is.) What is `t.timestamps :expires_at`? Maybe it should be `t.datetime :expires_at`?

Comment: Thanks, much guys, this was helpful, I changed to datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.timestamps` doesn't accept timestamp name, just hash/keyword arguments:

> `timestamps(options = {})`
>
> Adds timestamps (`created_at` and `updated_at`) columns to the table.
>
> `t.timestamps(null: false)`
>   [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-timestamps)

If you want to add `expires_at`, you need to add it using a correct date type (e.g. `datetime`:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      # ...
      t.datetime :expires_at
    end
  end
end
```